Gas estimation failed with unknown To address
I'm getting gas estimation errors leading to my transactions not going through. Here is the error message:
Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":256,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted\",\"data\":\"0x\"}}", error={"code":3,"data":"0x"}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"from\":\"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266\",\"to\":\"0x2ce1F0e20C1f69E9d9AEA83b25F0cEB69e2AA2b5\",\"data\":\"0x2fe69784000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bd342d3875ed9000000000000000000000000d9e1ce17f2641f24ae83637ab66a2cca9c378b9f\",\"value\":\"0x0\",\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x60f7b0ba\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":256,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://127.0.0.1:1234", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)

I read a similar problem on Go-Ethereum EstimateGas Errors that the "To" field was an unknown address and making sure a valid "To" address is defined will solve this issue. However, I'm not defining this "To" address anywhere in my code.
This is my Solidity code:
IUniswapV2Router router = IUniswapV2Router(routerAddress);
IERC20(swapPaths[0]).approve(routerAddress, type(uint256).max);
router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 0, swapPaths, address(this), block.timestamp);
IERC20(swapPaths[0]).approve(routerAddress, 0);

Where routerAddress is 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D (because I'm swapping on Uniswap v2)
amountIn and swapPaths varies, but an example that triggers a gas estimation failure error is 3328508713983705 and [0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, 0x630d98424efe0ea27fb1b3ab7741907dffeaad78, 0xae7ab96520de3a18e5e111b5eaab095312d7fe84, 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2] respectively.
My question - is 0x2ce1F0e20C1f69E9d9AEA83b25F0cEB69e2AA2b5 coming from Geth? Perhaps its used as a default value when no "To" address is defined? If so, what should this "To" address be?
